# Autolayout constraint is not working after animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I am little bit new at AutoLayout.I know already tons of question and tutorial available regarding this autoLayout but I have not found my solution.So Thanks in advance for any help.

What is my requirement?

I have to make UIView which will come to screen after pressing a button from the bottom side of the screen with animation.(Like Keyboard).I have made this UIView in a xib file using autoLayout.So far i have done like this.

In ViewDidLoad:

```
//Loading custom UIView 
containerView = [[SharingPickerView alloc] init];
[containerView loadingMenus:pickerData];
[self.view addSubview:containerView];
```

In this view it contatains (a scrollview then a page controller then a cancel button)

In ViewWillLayoutSubviews:

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{
[super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

//Changing the frame of view to bottom side of the screen so that we can animate it later from bottom to top later.

containerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, containerView.frame.size.height);
[containerView setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:231.0/255.0f green:231.0/255.0f blue:231.0/255.0f alpha:1.0f] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3]];
}
```

Now on press for animation.

```
-(void)sharePickerView{
   [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^(){
   containerView.frame = CGRectMake(0,self.view.frame.size.height-containerView.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, containerView.frame.size.width);
   } completion:^(BOOL isFinished){
  NSLog(@"Animation Finish");
   }];
}
```

Here i am re-framing the View for showing that animation but some bottom portion(cancel button of that view) is not showing in iPhone 6 simulator but it is showing perfectly iPhone 5s device.

Regards
Emon.

Comment: Here's a tutorial on how you can do static autolayout animations easily https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8KVKXlh6sKI

Answer (score 1):

try to use size constraints as outlets. Then you can easy change values of those constraints. It's not really recommended to modify frame when using auto-layout.

declare a property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint;
```

and in the implementation:

```
heightConstraint = self.view.frame.size.height;
```

Also this post may be helpful:
[AutoLayout, Constraints and Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19899323/autolayout-constraints-and-animation)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't reframe if you are using `NSAutoLayout`.

1. You have to install a constraint at bottom of the screen with the scroll and the view parent. Remember set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to NO when you instance the custom view.

[image]

2. Create an Outlet of this constraint.
3. When you need change animating

   ```
   _ctScrollBottom.constant = self.view.frame.size.height-containerView.frame.size.height;

   [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration
                    animations:^(){
                        [self.view  layoutIfNeeded];
                    }];
   ```

I took your "y" position calculation but I have not tested it ;)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to add constraints programmatically

1. First, set your `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO`

   ```
   containerView = [[SharingPickerView alloc] init];
   containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
   [containerView loadingMenus:pickerData];
   [self.view addSubview:containerView];
   ```
2. second, add constraints for height

   ```
   // for example, half height as view.

   self.heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
         constraintWithItem:containerView
                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                     toItem:self.view
                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                 multiplier:0.5
                   constant:0.0]
   [self.view addConstraint:self.heightConstraint];`
   ```

Hold this constraint as property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint;
```

Animate constraint changes as

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                 animations:^{
                     self.heightConstraint.constant += Value_to_change;
                     [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                 }];
```

Also, do not forget to add trailing and leading constraints + top constraint

Here is good tutorial for you 
http://www.thinkandbuild.it/learn-to-love-auto-layout-programmatically/

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26040569/2654425 may be very helpul as it deals with a similar situation.